# Saving array in data attribute and retrieving it using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm storing an array in a data attribute of a button.

the array is stored successfully but for some reason every time I try to access the array stored in the data attribute, I only get the the opening brackets of array and nothing else!

it just doesn't make sense to me...

This is my code:

```js
var array = [{"note": "Hey I love you!",
    "full_name": "Sarah James",
    "date_added": "14 September 2022"
},{
    "note": "Hey I love you too!",
    "full_name": "Billy Smith",
    "date_added": "15 September 2022"
}];


var stringed = JSON.stringify(array);
 
 
 $('.o').append('<button data-test="'+stringed+'" class="viewTicketBtn">Click Here</button>');
 
 
 $(document).on('click', '.viewTicketBtn', function(){ 
 var str = $(this).attr('data-test');
console.log(str);
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="o">

</div>
```

click on the Button and you will see the issue.

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are not aware, then `console.log(stringed)` will show you what value you will be inserting into the attribute. Now think about what that means, when you insert it using `data-test="'+stringed+'"`, where the double quotes are supposed to be the attribute value delimiters.

Comment: It works fine, it's because of the JSON which is wrongly formatted into HTML

Comment: *it doesn't make sense* - try: `console.log('<button data-test="'+stringed+'" class="viewTicketBtn">')` then copy the output into an HTML editor/validator/linter/IDE to see all the errors in the HTML.  https://jsfiddle.net/53y69kwq/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're using the `data` attribute in HTML. This can only store strings. You're correctly using `JSON.stringify()` to work around this, however the `"` within the JSON are breaking the HTML format. You can escape the double quotes in the HTML, but there is an easier way.

To fix the issue you can use jQuery's `data()` method to both get and set the value, as this will retain your object structure automatically.

Here's a working example:

```js
const array = [{
  "note": "Hey I love you!",
  "full_name": "Sarah James",
  "date_added": "14 September 2022"
}, {
  "note": "Hey I love you too!",
  "full_name": "Billy Smith",
  "date_added": "15 September 2022"
}];


$('<button class="viewTicketBtn">Click Here</button>').data('test', array).appendTo('.o');

$(document).on('click', '.viewTicketBtn', function() {
  const str = $(this).data('test');
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="o"></div>
```

Comment: _"This can only store strings."_ - they used `JSON.stringify`, so the value _is_ a string. The problem is the collision between the double quotes used as attribute delimiters, and the double quotes contained in the inserted value itself.

Comment: @CBroe indeed - I just addressed that in an edit

Answer (score 1):

Use other quotes - I swapped the `'` and `"` to handle the double quotes that JSON insists on.

See other answer for a jQuery method of just storing the array directly in a [data  method](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
var array = [{"note": "Hey I love you!",
    "full_name": "Sarah James",
    "date_added": "14 September 2022"
},{
    "note": "I'm in love with you too!",
    "full_name": "Billy Smith",
    "date_added": "15 September 2022"
}];


var stringed = JSON.stringify(array).replace(/'/g,"&quot;"); // make sure there are no ' in the text.
console.log(stringed)
 
 $('.o').append("<button data-test='"+stringed+"' class='viewTicketBtn'>Click Here</button>");
 
 
 $(document).on('click', '.viewTicketBtn', function(){ 
 var str = $(this).attr('data-test');
alert(str);
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="o"></div>
```

Comment: This works well until your text contains `'`, eg `"note": "Hey I'm in love with you!"`

Comment: Ok, we can continue this all day ;) - I added `&quot;` replacement